# how to use replace in nodejs for two symbols togather?

Tags: node.js

I have a data like {latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},{latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},{latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556} -- how can I replace  }, with ; in node. I tried the below code and got error.

```
data1 = "latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}
"
    var re = /\'},'\+/g
    data = data1.replace(re,';')

I wou
```

ld like to get output like

```
{latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57;{latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1;{latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you're getting an error is because of no double-quotes.
replace() is string function.

```js
data1 = "{latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},{latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},{latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}"
var re = /\'},'\+/g
data = data1.replace(re,';')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regexp specialist. But first of all, you have a trouble that `data1` is not a string. You need to put it in string literal `"` or `'`.

So you will have something like:

```
data1 = {latitude:1.9,longitude:103.57},{latitude:1.338,longitude:103.1},{latitude:1.33,longitude:103.7556}
```

Secondly, your regular expression won't work as I can see from regex101.com. 
You can try this:

```
data1.replace(/([^}]+)(,)([^{]+)/g, "$1;$3")
```